# Punctuation inside quotes

Tags: punctuation

In American English, the following sentences correctly use the punctuation.

> She told me "Don't talk to me like that!"

> She told me "I love you."

> When I hear "she is coming," I run in the opposite direction.

How would the translation in Italian of those sentences use the punctuation? In particular:

- Should I add a period after the quote in the first example?
- Is it correct to put the period inside the quote as in the second example?
- Does the comma in the third example go inside or outside the quote?

Comment: kiamlaluno, no, no, outside.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the same order:

- It depends (different Italian publishers have different rules for this; I think I can quote sources for both uses).
- No (but even here there is not a universal consensus). I'd write:

  > Mi disse “Ti amo”.

  But if a whole sentence or sequence of sentences are within quotes, the final period should be within as well (just like for brackets).
- Outside, definitely.